# How do use the navbar to trigger an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying for days. 
What i want to do is use the options in the navigation menu that i have to trigger onload event in java script/jquery. However, the events just doesnt fire up. I have tried using onselect and onclick as well but with no avail.
The event should bring data into my template.
Maybe im making a mistake that i  just cant see. or is there another better way to do this?

This is my Navigation bar. You can see the onselect functions that i was trying to use.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MEK Steel</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" >
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html#about">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a  href="about.html#history">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a  href="about.html#privacyPolicy" >Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a  href="about.html#termsAndConditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="about.html#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" class="active">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manufactured Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li onselect = "steelProducts()">
                            <a href="steelProducts.html">Steel Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li onselect = "steelDoors()">
                            <a href="steelDoors.html">Steel Doors</a>
                        </li>
                        <li onselect="digitalSafes()">
                            <a href="digitalSafes.html">Digital Safes</a>
                        </li >
                        <li onselect="securityEq()">
                            <a href="securityEquipment.html">Security Equipment</a>
                        </li>
                        <li onselect="storageSol()">
                            <a href="storageSolutions.html">Storage Solutions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li onselect="steelFur()"> 
                            <a href="steelFurniture.html">Steel Furniture</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

This is my javascript. i have only written one for testing purposes

```
function showTemplate(template, data){
var html    = template(data);
console.log(html);
$('#content').html(html);
}    
function securityEq(){
source   = $("#productsTemplate").html();
secEqTemp = Handlebars.compile(source); 
showTemplate(secEqTemp, data);
}
```

Comment: Try putting all you have done in a FiddleJS and post it here please.

Comment: where are used these functions steelProducts() and others ?

Comment: The `<a>` tag does it's action before the `onselect` can do anything. What are you trying to accomplish here exactly?

Comment: @edisoni i have just written one function ie securityEq for testing purposes.

Comment: @Chax im trying for the onselect to work before the a tag does. like i want to load data and put it in my template and then show the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you explained what you were trying to do

> @Chax im trying for the onselect to work before the a tag does. like i want to load data and put it in my template and then show the page.

I came up with this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){ // Bind a click event to my <a> tag
    var linkValue = $(this).attr('data-link'); // Retreive the value of data-link aka where we want to go
    // Do something, your logic
    
    
    window.location.href = linkValue; // Load the new page
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-link="http://www.google.com">I'm a link</a>
<!-- Notice that the tag below doesn't have a href attribute but does have a data-link attribute-->
```

What this code does is simple. We bind a click event onto every `<a>` tag in the DOM. When one of our tag is clicked, we execute the function. Note that you can differenciate button using a `switch`. Then we call the `window` object and make it call the call the page we want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').on('click', function (){
    alert($(this).html());
  });
});
```

You need to reference the anchor and not the list tag.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpoling/0gorp07k/)

Answer (score -1):

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko0q1nfx/4/) When i place the js code inside the html using `<script>` it works and events are fired